# Do we say '2 teams are close'

Tags: expressions

We use "a close match/contest" to describe a match where the result of the 2 teams is close. But can we use the word "close" to describe the 2 teams instead of the result/match.  Like saying "the 2 teams are close"?  Which word should we use to express the idea that the 2 competing teams perform similarly?

Answer (score 1):

A couple different idioms that might apply here are, *"The two teams were neck and neck"* or, *"It was down to the wire."*

> But can we use the word "close" to describe the 2 teams instead of the result/match. Like saying "the 2 teams are close"?

You *can*, but it doesn't sound the best. In this instance, I would use one of the idioms I mentioned above.

Side-note: The rule of using the word form of numbers less than 20 versus their number form would make using the number two in your excerpt incorrect. Although this was not exactly what you were asking, I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: is the expression 'the 2 teams are close' incorrect?

Comment: The expression 'two teams are close' is ambiguous between (1) they are both close to winning (or to some other definite accomplishment) and (2) they (or rather their scores) are close to each other (which is compatible with neither of them being close to winning).

Answer (score 0):

You can use “close” to refer to many things, including the score in a game, the abilities or skills of the players on two teams, or the offerings of two merchants. The context is necessary to reveal what it is you’re talking about.

The word close is also used with respect to distance, which is also made clear by context or additional words.

See https://onelook.com/?w=close&ls=a for dictionary sources. Note that the word can be used as a verb, noun, adjective.